# C++ unordered map - no viable overloaded operator[]

Tags: c++

I'm trying to build a memo of values that links a pair of ints to an int using an unordered_map.

```
int memo(pair<int, int> &p, unordered_map<pair<int, int>, int> &memo) {
    if (memo[p] != -1) {
    }
}
```

I thought I would be to access the values in the unordered_map with pair but I'm getting an error:

> no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::unordered_map<std::pair<int, int>, int>' and 'std::pair<int, int>')

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to use `std::pair` as the key for an unordered_map, which is undefined by default since the hash of a std::pair is not well defined. You need to define a hash value for your `std::pair` key.

https://www.techiedelight.com/use-std-pair-key-std-unordered_map-cpp/

Example from link:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <utility>

typedef std::pair<std::string,std::string> pair;

struct pair_hash
{
    template <class T1, class T2>
    std::size_t operator() (const std::pair<T1, T2> &pair) const
    {
        return std::hash<T1>()(pair.first) ^ std::hash<T2>()(pair.second);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<pair,int,pair_hash> unordered_map =
    {
        {{"C++", "C++11"}, 2011},
        {{"C++", "C++14"}, 2014},
        {{"C++", "C++17"}, 2017},
        {{"Java", "Java 7"}, 2011},
        {{"Java", "Java 8"}, 2014},
        {{"Java", "Java 9"}, 2017}
    };

    for (auto const &entry: unordered_map)
    {
        auto key_pair = entry.first;
        std::cout << "{" << key_pair.first << "," << key_pair.second << "}, "
                  << entry.second << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's so annoying that these two standard containers can't work together out of the box.

Comment: Yeah. The issue comes from the difference between std::map and std::unordered_map. std::map uses operator< for sorting, which is well defined for std::pair depending on the types inside of it. However, std::unordered_map doesn't use operator< since it is unordered, so it has to rely on the hash of std::pair, which is not well defined.